# Is there a way to load plugin.xml as an object?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have a plug-in project opened in the workspace. Is there an API which could help to change the plugin.xml? I don't want to parse it as an xml file.

Comment: Can you say more specifically what you want to change? The plugin.xml is read into a registry (or registries, I forget) by a standard mechanism. I don't think it's mutable, but if we know more we might be able to help you.

Comment: I want to change ID, Version and Extensions.

Comment: Do you want to change those at run time?  Or is this something you want to do as part of an automated development process?

Comment: It is "automated development process". I have a plug-in project and I want to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "good" way to do this as the PDE guys did not open their APIs to modify manifest files (MANIFEST.MF, plugin.xml, etc). You can only access those information in read only with their APIs. That being said, if you are not afraid of using internal code, you can have a look at PDEModelUtility and ModelModification. These classes are used in the OrganizeManifestProcessor.